# Using a Correlated Subquery within a Left Join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, left-join, where-clause

I need a fresh set of eyes on this query. Without getting mega in depth in this code my problem is I'm doing a left join to pull from the TXP_Digital_Signatures (tds) table which stores signatures to the most current version of Treatment Plans (txp_master txp). What this code is doing is bringing back results where tds.signed is null (no signature) or marked N (No). This works, but what this report has done is show people what No's need to become yes, but that is leaving the No left behind, so if there is a more recent Yes then the No in that version of the tds.plan_id it is still pulling that plan_id where I no longer want it where the most recent signature status is a Y (yes), etc. The code snippet below added to the where statement works, but it hides all No's even if there is not a newer Y (yes).

```
tds.date = (select Max(date) from TXP_Digital_Signatures where tds.plan_id = txp.plan_id)
```

Can anyone think of a way to either add a correlated subquery to the left join, so it only pulls the max(tds.date) for each tds.plan_id or how to rework my where statements so the no's without a newer yes and the null's still show up. I really don't want to redo the entire report as a grouped report if I can help it where I feel it'll break a ton of stuff on me and basically have me redoing this report from scratch. SQL 2008 R2

```
SELECT  case_status,
    CONVERT(CHAR(10), episode_open_date, 101)AS 'Enrolled' ,
    txp.patient_id, 
    p.lname+', ' + p.fname AS 'Client',
    CONVERT(CHAR(10), txp.effective_date, 101)AS 'Effective', 
    CONVERT(CHAR(10), next_review_date, 101)AS 'Review',
    txp.signed,
    (SELECT location_code FROM staff s WHERE s.staff_id = txp_coordinator_id) AS 'Clinic',
    (SELECT s.lname+', ' +s.fname FROM staff s WHERE s.staff_id = txp_coordinator_id) AS 'Coordinator',
    (SELECT s.lname+', ' +s.fname FROM staff s WHERE s.staff_id = ts.team_member_id ) AS 'Team', 
    ts.signed,
    tds.signed as 'Patient Sig'
FROM txp_master txp join patient p ON p.patient_id = txp.patient_id and p.episode_id = txp.episode_id
    join txp_signature ts on ts.plan_id = txp.plan_id and ts.version_no = txp.version_no and ts.team_member_id <> txp.txp_coordinator_id
    left join TXP_Digital_Signatures tds on tds.plan_id = txp.plan_id

where p.case_status = 'A' and 
txp.status <> 'er' and patient_signed_date is null 
and tds.signed is null or tds.signed = 'N'
and txp.effective_date > '2016-12-31 00:00:00.000'
and tds.date = (select Max(date) from TXP_Digital_Signatures where tds.plan_id = txp.plan_id)

order by patient_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query should work if you correct the sub-query, like this:

```
(select Max(date) from TXP_Digital_Signatures x where x.plan_id = tds.plan_id)
```

currently, you are not filtering the sub-query `TXP_Digital_Signatures`.

One other thing to take note of is that you have a `LEFT JOIN` on `TXP_Digital_Signatures tds` yet you include it on the `WHERE` clause. This will convert it to an `INNER JOIN`. So decide on what join you require and change accordingly.

If you want results regardless of `TXP_Digital_Signatures tds` then move those conditions to the `ON` clause.

If you only want results based on `TXP_Digital_Signatures tds` then change to `INNER JOIN`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm a little confused. Where do I put the sub query? Just in the select? That shows what the max date is, but doesn't hide the N results with a newer yes in the results. I'm also a little confused on how you want me to switch my join around. I want results regardless of of TXP_Digital_signatures where I need the null results that do not have a signature, but not exactly sure what to change from your description. Thank you and sorry I'm a code noob.

Comment: The suggestion is that the final line of your code should look like that. The problem with the code you posted is that `tds` isn't referring to the instance of TDS in that subquery but the one in the main body of the query. It needs it's own alias.

Comment: Any `WHERE` clause which references tds (other than `tds.field = NULL`) will filter out cases where there is no TDS record. If you don't want to do that, you need to move those lines into the `ON` clause for the relevant `JOIN`.

Comment: Oh. I think I get it now. Sorry. I had reworked my code prior to your post more and had confused myself. Let me do a little spot checking, but I'm pretty sure you've got the check mark. Thank you so much.